# presto - Get date for the last most recent Saturday

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I want to always get the date for the most recent last Saturday since current date, and I'm trying this query:

```
date_trunc('week', current_date) - interval '2' day
```

This would work if today is Monday - Saturday, but if the day is Sunday, it would return the last Saturday rather than yesterday.

Example:

If I put 2021-07-18 as current_date, I want it to return 2021-07-17, but it actually returns 2021-07-10.

I guess this is because presto treat a week as Monday - Sunday, rather then Sunday - Saturday?

How can I solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two days, truncate, then subtract two days:

```
select date_trunc('week', current_date + interval '2' day) - interval '2' day
```